# How to only delete encoding=UTF8 from xml file

Tags: java, xml, encoding

```
public static void saveXMLDocument(Document xodrDoc, String absoluteFileName) throws Exception{
    //write the content into xml file                    
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xodrDoc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(absoluteFileName));
    transformer.transform(source, result);
}
```

So this is how my output file looks like when i try deleting only the "encoding" attribute:

```
<OpenDRIVE>
<header date="Wed May 23 12:21:34 2018" east="0.0000000000000000e+00" name="" north="0.0000000000000000e+00" revMajor="1" revMinor="4" south="0.0000000000000000e+00" version="1.00" west="0.0000000000000000e+00">
</header>
<road id="7" junction="-1" length="1.0000000000000000e+03" name="">
    <link>
    </link>
    <planView>
        <geometry hdg="0.0000000000000000e+00" length="1.0000000000000000e+01" s="0.0000000000000000e+00" x="0.0000000000000000e+00" y="0.0000000000000000e+00">
            <line/>
        </geometry>
        <geometry hdg="0.0000000000000000e+00" length="22" s="1.0000000000000000e+01" x="1.0000087425259599e+01" y="0.0000000000000000e+00">
            <arc curvature="0.10"/>
        </geometry>
    </planView>
```

What should the output be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<OpenDRIVE>
<header revMajor="1" revMinor="4" name="" version="1.00" date="Wed May 23 12:21:34 2018" north="0.0000000000000000e+00" south="0.0000000000000000e+00" east="0.0000000000000000e+00" west="0.0000000000000000e+00">
</header>
<road name="" length="1.0000000000000000e+03" id="7" junction="-1">
    <link>
    </link>
    <planView>
        <geometry s="0.0000000000000000e+00" x="0.0000000000000000e+00" y="0.0000000000000000e+00" hdg="0.0000000000000000e+00" length="1.0000000000000000e+01">
            <line/>
        </geometry>
        <geometry s="1.0000000000000000e+01" x="1.0000087425259599e+01" y="0.0000000000000000e+00" hdg="0.0000000000000000e+00" length="9.9000000000000000e+02">
            <arc curvature="5.0000000000000001e-04"/>
        </geometry>
    </planView>
```

So I know I should not delete the encoding part but it is important to me as otherwise I can't work with this file because I use a special tool for the loading. The excpected output is a pattern I load in my programm. After saving it again I get the current output.

The xml file has to contain the standalone attribute but not the encoding part.

Comment: @TobySpeight better?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the encoding? And if you *really* want to remove it, can you use command line tools eg `sed`?

Comment: OpenDrive scenario developer. In this tool I load the file and represent it graphically BUT if  i have the encoding part init i can't load it

Comment: So can you use command line tools?

Comment: @Bohemian no i can  only load it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `ProcessingInstruction` which lets you configure any tag you want to append.

In this example I am adding a tag "xml" with the custom data that you specified in your case.

```
ProcessingInstruction newPI = xodrDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=\"1.0\" standard=\"yes\"");
            xodrDoc.insertBefore(newPI, xodrDoc.getDocumentElement());
```

I have created a sample class to test adding the custom xml header.

```
public class SaveXmlWithCustomXmlHeader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xmlString = "<a><b></b><c></c></a>";

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        Document document = null;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        saveXMLDocument(document, "hello.xml");
    }

    public static void saveXMLDocument(Document xodrDoc, String absoluteFileName) throws Exception {
        // add custom xml tag
        ProcessingInstruction newPI = xodrDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=\"1.0\" standard=\"yes\"");
        xodrDoc.insertBefore(newPI, xodrDoc.getDocumentElement());

        //write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xodrDoc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(absoluteFileName));

        transformer.transform(source, result);
    }
}
```

Output of hello.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standard="yes"?><a>
<b/>
<c/>
</a>
```

*UPDATE:*
There seems to be a problem when using `ProcessingInstruction` while writing to the file, as it does not indent correctly the xml header from the rest of the xml data.

Normally, this would not change in anyway the processing the xml, as it is just a human readable thing, not a technical issue.

But for the ones that do care, here is the alternative to the `ProcessingInstruction`:

```
public static void saveXMLDocument(Document xodrDoc, String absoluteFileName) throws Exception {
        // add custom xml tag
        //write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        writer.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"yes\"?>").append("\n");
        final DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xodrDoc);
        transformer.transform(source, new StreamResult(writer));
        try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(absoluteFileName))) {
            bufferedWriter.write(writer.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried it out but when I save the loaded pattern i get 3 xm headers: `<?xml version="1.0" standard="yes"?>
<?xml version="1.0" standard="yes"?>
<?xml version="1.0" standard="yes"?>
`

Comment: @plshm you got to give me more info then. Do you call the saveXmlDocument in a sequence of 3 files by any chance? Maybe the reference to the document is the same or something?

Comment: well if think the reference is the same. can I copy the document somehow and than call it?

Comment: I would say you should copy the `ProcessingInstruction` outside the saving method, before doing the for loop and it should create the xml only once.

Comment: thx, but do you know why I have in the first line this: `<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?><OpenDRIVE>` i want open drive to be at 2nd line in the editor.

Comment: @plshm, I saw the same thing. I tried a few ideas, nothing worked so far. In any case, I think it only visually (from a human perspective) it looks a bit weird, but technically you shouldn't have any problem with processing the data. I will try to see if I can come up with a different solution later

Comment: @plshm, update my answer with an alternative. I didn't get any luck with the `ProcessingInstruction` variant to separate the xml header from the rest of the content. Hope this helps

Comment: @plshm, the alternative would need to happen inside your own save to file method, instead of only once, if I am not mistaken

Comment: thank you. it works. concerning the performance, is the second (current) approach slower?

Comment: @plshm, I would make the header xml literal (i.e."<?xml ...>") a constant as a small improvement. If would say that you'll want to test that out for yourself, because I have too much information about the data being processed and see if it's a bit slower, although I don't think it would be a tremendous difference. If the second approach is slower, go with the first one.

Comment: Thanks, for PDF/A i searched for         transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");

Answer (score 0):

These requirements are stupid, but whatever.

There is a reason why XML is an industry standard. It's a simple text format that can be easily tinkered.

After you've written your XML file, load it back into a String in memory, add `"<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"yes\"?>"` at the beginning of it, and write that back into your file.

Answer (score -1):

Use `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/encoding=".*?"//' myfile.xml
```